# Rails form_for select default option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form_for select where the options are being defined from within the model. I am trying to get it to display a placeholder option but cannot figure out how to.

**The Model:**

```
class Factoid < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :title

  validates_presence_of :description, :name, :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :title


  NAMES = "Angela", "Geordie", "Jared", "Jennifer", "Kevin", "Matthew", "Oscar", "Owen", "Regina", "Todd", "Vaibhavi", "Zack"


  UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES = ["id", "updated_at"]

  def self.ransackable_attributes auth_object = nil
    (column_names - UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRIBUTES) + _ransackers.keys
  end

end
```

**The Form:**

```
<%= form_for @factoid, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.select :name, :collection => Factoid::NAMES %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                factoids_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The second issue is that the dropdown menu is displaying the word "collection" at the top of it (See screenshot below). How do I get read of that. Ideally I want to have a dropdown menu with a placeholder of "Names" that is also displayed at the top when the dropdown menu is opened. 
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: In what situation would you like it to display a placeholder? if the attribute is undefined?

Comment: When you first come to the page. This is a "new" factoid.

Comment: cool, just wanted to check. I'll answer in a sec.

Comment: @MikeH-R sorry something came up. I responded below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your text field try something like:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field', value: 'my_default_value' %>
```

for your select try:

```
<%= f.select :name, Factoid::NAMES %>
```

See [the docs for select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) and [the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags) for typical usage (I think the method I've shown you will not work upon submitting the form, see the guides linked for explanation, I'm not sure though).

Comment: That got rid of the "collection" but I still need a placeholder for the select.

Comment: Read [the docs for select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html), that tells you how to do it.

Comment: For clarity, the solution was ```<%= f.select :name, Factoid::NAMES, include_blank: 'None' %>```

Thanks Mike!